# OpenCV on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ubuntu

I've just updated my system from ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and now I can't compile anymore any C program that contain references to OpenCV libraries

I've already tried to reinstall OpenCV (I use the **2.1 version**) but I'm stuck with this error:

```
/tmp/ccArHTZL.o: In function `main':
z.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
z.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
z.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
z.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
z.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
z.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In order to install OpenCV I've always followed this procedure:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcv2.1 libcv-dev libcvaux2.1 libcvaux-dev libhighgui2.1
     libhighgui-dev opencv-doc python-opencv

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/opencv/lib
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/opencv/lib/pkgconfig

$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
     -I/usr/include/opencv

$ pkg-config --libs opencv
     -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux -lml

$ g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm hello.c
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use **pkg-config** to your favor?

```
g++ hello.c -o hello `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: You should always put the libraries at the end of the row : gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test `pkg-config opencv --libs` . Somehow this became important after I upgraded Ubuntu to 11.10.

Comment: Guys, this advice, putting libraries to the END.. oh god, you saved me from another frustration!

Comment: YEAH!!!!!!!! @DimitarSlavchev you just fixed nearly two weeks fo heartache, headache and pain!  Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of some changes from gcc 4.5 to gcc 4.6

Try this command instead (i.e., move the libraries to the end, instead of at the beginning of your command line) -- it works for me:

g++ -I/usr/include/opencv hello.c -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on kubuntu 10.10 so I'm not really familiar how does 11.10 work, but the most common answer to problems with not finding libraries is to use **ldconfig** with **sudo**. It'll refresh libraries database. If that doesn't help, look into **/usr/lib**, **/usr/lib64** and **/usr/lib32**, because its the default place where apt-get throws libraries in. When you find the libraries, change the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** so it contains the directory. I don't think that /home/opencv/lib is where they are, but i don't know Your environment

Comment: I've found all the libcv.so libraries in `/usr/lib`. Then I provided to change the path `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib` but I continue to get the same error

Comment: Not a linker expert here, but have You tried to compile it without meddling with PKG_CONFIG and LD_LIBRARY_PATH? i belive that unless You've compiled some libraries from source the defaults are O.K. Another thing is that as I see You use g++ to compile a c program. There is a slight chance that this is the issue. You could also try if c++ api works. just to e sure that the problem lies on the linker-libraries-searching side not on the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to 11.04 on my laptop and having similar issues.  I would try building the latest version of OpenCV (2.3.1) and see if this fixes anything, this seemed to fix quite a few issues for me.

Comment: I previously tried the 2.3.1 but I encountered A LOT OF ISSUES that forced me to downgrade to the 2.1 version. So unfortunately for me the upgrade to 2.3.1 is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command, it worked for me:

> gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` opencv.c -o open_cv `pkg-config --libs opencv`