# Can't compile first opencv program, '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv'

Tags: image, gcc, graphics, opencv

```
g++ cv.cpp -o cv -I /usr/local/include/opencv
    -L /usr/local/lib  -lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```c
#include <cv.h>
#include <ml.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
//#include <cxtypes.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "bal.png" );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
    return 0;
}
```

It's 32 bit,

```
locate libcv
/usr/lib/libcv.so.2.1
/usr/lib/libcv.so.2.1.0
```

---

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

-I/usr/local/include/opencv
-I/usr/local/include  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

---

Installed OpenCV-2.4.0 in /usr/local, I also have a system python-opencv.
Where am i doing the mistake? What should i do?

Comment: If you are on 64bit system, you should probably use `-L /usr/local/lib64`. Anyway, try to `locate libcv.so`

Comment: It's 32 bit, `locate libcv` = /usr/lib/libcv.so.2.1
/usr/lib/libcv.so.2.1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV on ubuntu 11.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781302/opencv-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen from the [changelog](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#22) published on the OpenCV site (for version 2.2), the library names have changed from version 2.2 onwards, so the library names used to link for version 2.1 cannot be used to compile with version 2.4 (i.e. `libcv.so` which is linked through `-lcv` is not valid library name for version > 2.1 as so on ). You need to pass the libraries which are part of the new version of OpenCV (which have been listed through `pkg-config` command). You can make use of `pkg-config` to pass the compiler & linker flags something on these lines : `g++ cv.cpp -o cv $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have version 2.1 in `/usr/lib` while the new installed version 2.4 is in `/usr/local/lib`, need to fix that and make sure the lib `ld` finds is the one you compiled/linked for.

Comment: How can i make sure that ld finds the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the opencv 2.4 and was a compatibility issue. If you want to use the latest version, remove previous version of opencv to avoid this problems or lib location's problems when you compile.