# Accessing OpenCV Image processing library for OpenCV-2.4.3 for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, image-processing, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV on ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781302/opencv-on-ubuntu-11-10)

I am a new user of OpenCV and Linux so maybe my question is very obvious; if so I apologize.

I downloaded OpenCV version 2.4.3 for Linux which looks like the latest version. I have been trying to do some of the tutorials that require the image processing library. These tutorials all use #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp".

However, after doing a "locate imgproc.hpp" in the terminal I come up with no results. It looks as though the image processing library is not included in OpenCV version 2.4.3 or somehow I downloaded it incorrectly. I seem to have all of the other header and hpp files though.

Is there a way to access the image processing library?

Thank you

Comment: what IDE do you use? visual studio express?

Comment: Have you compiled the library using Cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *install* OpenCV, just downloading it don't write correct paths to your system in a magical way.
What Linux distribution do you use? the right way to install such things is to use package manager and repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The location of OpenCV headers and libraries should be available using pkg-config command. pkg-config --cflags opencv locates the headers, pkg-config --libs opencv locates the libraries. You can directly use it in your compilation command, such as `g++ main.cpp -o main`pkg-config`--cflags --libs opencv`

pkg-config should be btw backquotes``, I'll edit my answer as soon as I find how to make them appear properly